# ¿Error los datos del artículo no se esta guardando en la session array?

Tags: array, php7, session

Estoy tratando de asignarle atributos a ciertos productos, en casos especiales como ropa, zapatos entre otros artículos, donde se debe incluir talla y color, he realizado lo siguiente agregando `color` y `size`:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST)) {
        $itemId = isset($_POST['itemId']) ? $_POST['itemId'] : "";
        $item_color = isset($_POST['color']) ? $_POST['color'] : "";
        $item_size = isset($_POST['size']) ? $_POST['size'] : "";

        if (is_numeric($itemId)) {

            $limit_data = 1;
            $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id_product, type_product, title_product, price_old, price FROM tbl_products WHERE id_product=? LIMIT ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("ii", $itemId, $limit_data);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result(
                    $id_product,
                    $type_product,
                    $title_product,
                    $price_old,
                    $price
            );
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->close();

            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and isset($_POST['qtyupdate'])) {

                for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['qtyupdate']); $i++) {
                    $key = $_POST['arr_key_' . $i]; //arr_key_0, arr_key_1, arr_key_2
                    $_SESSION['qty'][$key] = $_POST['qtyupdate'][$i];
                }
            } else {
                //Add new register in base session
                $qty = isset($_POST['qty']) ? $_POST['qty'] : 1;
                if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {

                    $_SESSION['cart'][] = array(
                        'id_product' => $id_product,
                        'title_product' => $title_product,
                        'price_old' => $price_old,
                        'price' => $price,
                        'qty' => $qty,
                        'color' => $item_color,
                        'size' => $item_size
                    );
                    $_SESSION['qty'][] = array();
                }

                if ($type_product === "digital") {
                    if(!in_array($itemId, $_SESSION['cart'])){
                        array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $itemId);
                        $key = array_search($itemId, $_SESSION['cart']);
                        $_SESSION['qty'][$key] = $qty;

                        echo json_encode(['status'=> TRUE, 'message'=>"<strong>El producto ha sido añadido a su carrito.</strong>"]);
                        exit;
                    } else {
                        echo json_encode(['status'=> FALSE, 'message'=>"<strong>Este producto ya está añadido al carrito.</strong>"]);
                        exit;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (in_array($itemId, $_SESSION['cart'])) {
                        //The product already added to the shopping cart is updated +1
                        $key = array_search($itemId, $_SESSION['cart']);
                        $_SESSION['qty'][$key] = $_SESSION['qty'][$key] + $qty;
                        echo json_encode(['status'=> TRUE, 'message'=>"<strong>Se ha actualizado su producto +1.</strong>"]);
                        exit;
                    } else {
                        //The product is added to the shopping cart for the first time
                        array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $itemId);
                        $key = array_search($itemId, $_SESSION['cart']);
                        $_SESSION['qty'][$key] = $qty;
                        echo json_encode(['status'=> TRUE, 'message'=>"<strong>El producto ha sido añadido a su carrito.</strong>"]);
                        exit;
                    }
                }

            }
        } else {
            echo json_encode(['status'=> FALSE, 'message'=>"<strong>Error, producto no encontrado.</strong>"]);
            exit;
        }
    }
?>
```

Pero al imprimir los datos `print_r($_SESSION['cart']);` me muestra este resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
```

Debería imprimirme algo como esto:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_product] => 1
            [title_product] => prueba
            [price_old] => 12
            [price] => 10
            [qty] => 1
            [color] => amarillo
            [size] => L
        )
)
```

La idea de esto es poder luego imprimir dichos datos en el carro de compra y, listarlo de la siguiente manera, como se puede observar en el carrito a imprimir el resultado se debe reflejar el mismo producto pero en caso de que los datos sean distintos esto se debe duplicar como si fuera un producto diferente:

```
Item        Size     Color  Price  Quantity  Subtotal
prueba        L      red     5.00     2        10.00
prueba        M      red     5.00     3        15.00
prueba        XL     red     5.00     1         5.00
prueba        XL     black   5.00     1         5.00
```

Este es el código que me va listar el resultado en el carro de compras, claro que aquí se lo debe modificar dado a que de esta manera no me va duplicar el producto cuando los valores sean diferentes, creo que aquí debo usar un `foreach` en vez de consultar datos e imprimir con el `while`:

```
<?php
    session_start();
 
    $items = (isset($_SESSION['cart']) && is_array($_SESSION['cart'])) ? $_SESSION['cart'] : array();
    $itemCount = count($items);
 
    $qty = (isset($_SESSION['qty']) && is_array($_SESSION['qty'])) ? $_SESSION['qty'] : array();
    $couponDiscount = (isset($_SESSION['couponCode']));
 
    $total = 0;
    $num = 1;
    $meQty = 0;
    $itemId = "";
    $meCount = $itemCount;
 
    foreach ($qty as $id_product => $valueqty) {
        //$meQty = $meQty + $valueqty;
        $meQty = (is_numeric($valueqty)) ?  ($meQty + $valueqty ) :  ($meQty +0);
    }
 
    foreach ($items as $id_product => $item) {
        $itemId = $itemId . $item . ",";
    }
 
    $array = explode(',', $itemId);
    $strMarcas  = str_repeat('?,', count($array) - 1) . '?';
    $strTipos = str_repeat('i', count($array));
 
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id_product, title_product, subtitle_product, price_old, price FROM tbl_products WHERE id_product in ($strMarcas)");
    $stmt->bind_param($strTipos, ...$array);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($id_product, $title_product, $subtitle_product, $price_old, $price);
    $get_coupon = isset($_GET['couponCode']) ? $_GET['couponCode'] : '';
 
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $key = array_search($id_product, $items);
        $total = $total + $price * $qty[$key];
?>
    <div class="items relative">
        <div class="bsk-item flex">
            <div class="timg">
                <img src="https://i...content-available-to-author-only...g.com/vi/ZxrUVuOqsy0/maxresdefault.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="heading bsk ellipsis"><p><?php echo $title_product; ?></p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bsk-price">$<?php echo number_format($price,2); ?></div>
        <div class="bsk-quantity"><?php echo $qty[$key]; ?></div>
        <div class="bsk-subtotal">$<?php echo number_format(($price * $qty[$key]),2); ?></div>
        <div class="delete">
            <span title="Eliminar" class="removeCart" id="<?php echo $id_product; ?>">
                <i class="icon-delete"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
    }
    $stmt->close();
?>
```

Y, este es mi código ajax https://jsfiddle.net/5k381gy4/ mediante lo siguiente agrego el producto al carrito:

```
<span title="Añadir al carrito" class="addCart buy" id="1">Añadir a la cesta</span>
```

Con los nuevos atributos estoy obligado a utilizar el mismo ajax pero enviando datos por medio de un `form` dado a los nuevos atributos de campos `input` de tipo `radio` que voy a utilizar para el tema de `color` y talla `size`.

La estructura de la base de datos o tabla de datos, solo estoy usando una tabla sencilla, esta compuesta por `id_product, title_product, subtitle_product, price_old, price`

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Si estoy agregando `session_start();`

Comment: Hola, en algún momento llamó `session_start();`, para que PHP llame los gestores de almacenamiento de sesiones

Comment: @rene Es un poco extraño, aunque no realizara lo que indicas no cambiaría el valor del array a : (   [0] => 1   )

Comment: No entiendo la lógica de este código, quizá si explicas un poco eso podrás obtener una respuesta óptima y clara. ¿Por qué unos datos vienen de la base de datos y otras datos vienen de otra parte? ¿Cómo se relacionan ambas fuentes de datos? ¿Cuáles son los criterios que deben aplicarse para obtener el resultado final que esperas? Nada de eso es explicado y da la impresión de que lo único que interesa es hacer funcionar un código erróneo (y quizá mal planteado). Cuando hay errores de lógica, aunque resuelvas el problema ahora, quizá vuelvas a tener problemas y más graves, más adelante.

Comment: @A.Cedano Hola, he actualizado mi pregunta, espero sea clara ahora :)

Comment: Aún no entiendo lo que te plantee en mi anterior comentario. Es extraño que tengas por un lado información en una base de datos y luego quieras agregar cosas a esa información, es como si no hubieses diseñado correctamente tu modelo de datos. Aparte de eso, el contexto no queda explicado con claridad y eso dificulta tener una idea clara de lo que intentas hacer aquí. Repito: a mi juicio, no se trata sólo de hacer funcionar un código sea como sea, si ese código está mal planteado o la lógica está mal planteada, hacer funcionar el código será sólo una solución ilusoria.

Comment: @A.Cedano Creo entender, el sistema anterior lo que hacía es agregar el producto al carro de compras mediante el ID del producto y este lo procesaba en la consulta donde lista los productos, pero como dice el SO, al agregar otros datos necesarios como color o talla entonces está queriendo agregar esa información y los otros datos del producto en el `$_SESSION[cart]` pero tiene problemas, dado que esos valores se agregan pero se vuelve a reemplazar como ya lo mencionó **Jorgesys** tiene sentido que lo realice de esa manera de la primera estructura del código `PHP` ya que luego esos datos...

Comment: @A.Cedano Debe procesarlos desde un `foreach` porque en la segunda estructura del código `PHP` no podría hacerlo de esa manera ya que se está listando los productos pero mediante del `id` del producto de esa manera no es posible duplicar los productos cuando sea el mismo pero con una opción diferente ya sea talla o color.

Comment: @Fernando Entonces debes probar alguna de las respuestas, para solucionar el error que presentas al agregar el producto, con todos los datos que mencionas para que luego con un `foreach` liste los productos y cuando uno esto sea distinto al agregado entonces duplicarlo, creo que con `foreach` se puede hacer sin emplear otros procedimientos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primera instancia pensé que el problema sería el llamado a:

```
array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $itemId);
```

pero en este caso se imprimiría

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_product] => 1
            [title_product] => prueba
            [price_old] => 12
            [price] => 10
            [qty] => 1
            [color] => amarillo
            [size] => L
        )

    [1] => 1
)
```

Por lo tanto el código que muestras el valor del array debería ser como lo describes:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_product] => 1
            [title_product] => prueba
            [price_old] => 12
            [price] => 10
            [qty] => 1
            [color] => amarillo
            [size] => L
        )

)
```

La única forma de obtener el valor que indicas es que lo estés modificando en algún otro punto, por ejemplo:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][0] = 1; //Modifica valor de array.
print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
```

se obtendría:

```
(
    [0] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un poco revuelta la lógica, porque no creas previamente el arreglo e insertas el producto, pero solo el primero, porque las siguientes veces, ya no entra en este bloque:

```
            if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
                $_SESSION['cart'][] = array(
                    'id_product' => $id_product,
                    'title_product' => $title_product,
                    'price_old' => $price_old,
                    'price' => $price,
                    'qty' => $qty,
                    'color' => $item_color,
                    'size' => $item_size
                );
            }
```

Más adelante, vuelves a insertar, pero solo ID:

```
                // Es lo mismo que $_SESSION['cart'][] = $itemId
                array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $itemId);
```

Entonces, el primer producto en el carrito debería tener la estructura deseada, pero los demás solo van a tener ID.

### Posible solución:

Lo primero que necesitas hacer es verificar que existe la variable en sesión, de lo contrario, crearla:

```
<?php
// Verificar variable
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    // Inicializar como arreglo vacío
    $_SESSION['cart'] = [];
}
```

También es conveniente crear un arreglo para devolver el resultado y lo vas a actualizar de acuerdo al resultado:

```
$res = ['status' => 'TRUE', 'message' => 'El producto fue agregado al carrito.'];
```

La variable `$_POST` siempre existe, aunque si está vacía, `isset($_POST)` devolverá falso; sin embargo, es recomendable verificar que existe el elemento a buscar:

```
if(isset($_POST['itemId'])) {
    $itemId = isset($_POST['itemId']) ? $_POST['itemId'] : "";
    $item_color = isset($_POST['color']) ? $_POST['color'] : "";
    $item_size = isset($_POST['size']) ? $_POST['size'] : "";

    if(is_numeric($itemId)) {
        $limit_data = 1;
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id_product, type_product, title_product, price_old, price FROM tbl_products WHERE id_product=? LIMIT ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ii", $itemId, $limit_data);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result(
                $id_product,
                $type_product,
                $title_product,
                $price_old,
                $price
        );
        // Debes validar si existe el producto
        if(!$stmt->fetch()) {
            $res = ['status' => 'FALSE', 'message' => 'El producto no existe en el catálogo'];
        } else {
```

En lugar de manejar las variables `cart` y `qty` dentro de sesión, te sugiero que guardes la cantidad en el elemento correspondiente y, además, asignar ID de producto como índice del arreglo.

Por lo pronto, si `$itemId` no es numérico, no vas a poder realizar la actualización de cantidad aquí, eso se debe pasar al final.

```
            //Add new register in base session
            $qty = isset($_POST['qty']) ? $_POST['qty'] : 1;
            // Verificar si ya existe
            if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'][$itemId])) {
                // No existe, hay que crearlo
                $_SESSION['cart'][$itemId] = [
                    'id_product' => $id_product,
                    'title_product' => $title_product,
                    'price_old' => $price_old,
                    'price' => $price,
                    'qty' => $qty,
                    'color' => $item_color,
                    'size' => $item_size
                ];
                // No necesitas modificar la variable de resultado
            } elseif($type_product === "digital") {
                // El producto es digital y ya existe en carrito
                // No se agrega, solo se actualiza la variable de resultado
                $res = ['status' => 'FALSE', 'message' => 'Este producto ya existe en el carrito'];
                } else {
                    // El proudcto ya existe en el carrito
                    // hay que actualizar la cantidad
                    $_SESSION['cart'][$itemId]['qty'] += $qty;
                }
            }
        } // endif fetch
    } else {
        $res = ['status' => 'FALSE', 'message' => 'Selecciona un producto para agregar al carrito'];
    } // endif is_numeric
```

Parece que envías un arreglo para actualizar la cantidad de todos los productos en el carrito y se debe manejar aparte. Solo falta ver tu HTML para saber qué cambios se deben hacer:

```
} elseif(isset($_POST['qtyupdate'])) {
    // Aquí es donde vas a actualizar las cantidades
} else {
    $res = ['status' => 'FALSE', 'message' => 'Acción inválida'];
} // endif $_POST['itemId']
```

Al final del script envías la variable `$res`:

```
echo json_encode($res);
```

**Nota:** No copies el código porque no tengo forma de probarlo; trata de entender cómo funciona y, solo entonces, actualiza tu script.

Comment: Hola, he actualizado mi pregunta, con la otra información que pregunta, espero ahora este un poco más clara.